# JBoss is getting SHUTDOWN automatically in linux

Tags: java, jboss, server

I have deployed my application in jboss-4.0.2RC1. It is working fine. But after some time unexpectedly **jboss** is getting shutdown.

Please find the below logs

```
2015-09-21 21:09:28,995 INFO  [org.jboss.system.server.Server] JBoss SHUTDOWN: Undeploying all packages

2015-09-21 21:09:28,995 DEBUG [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread] Notified to shutdown

2015-09-21 21:09:28,996 DEBUG [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Undeploying
```

I am not able to find the root cause?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

What operating system is hosting your jboss? There are a number of reasons this could happen depending on your configuration. For instance, if you are running on Windows and running JBoss as a service, it will shutdown upon server logoff, unless you have added to your run.conf.bat something like:

```
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrs
```

Comment: LInux environment. -Xrs means it restrict the shutdown using Operation System by ctrl+c etc right. But in my case,  I left the server whole night and i came on morning this shutdown happend.